# WP Template Hierarchy

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

Is this an up to date WP template hierarchy:

[image]

The one one the WP site is not as clear to me.

Comment: I'm voting to close as "not a real question". Try the Developers group in Google+.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is correct. This hierarchy reflects what's listed on the Codex Wordpress Template Hierarchy (http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy) but in a more simplified manner.

Comment: Are the yellow texts in the Codex image supposed to represent dynamic data?

Comment: The image from WPTUTS doesn't have `comments-popup.php`, `$mimetype.php`, `$subtype.php`, etc. while Codex does.